# jstack understanding

Tags: jboss5.x, jstack

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0 in a production environment and the shutdown time is quite long at times(>10 minutes). I've used jstack during one of the shutdown operations but I can't really understand its output. I'm attaching a snippet if there is some one who can help me.

Thank you.

```
"Thread-7326 (group:HornetQ-remoting-threads318818410-409317605)" prio=10 tid=0x000000004097b000 nid=0xbae waiting on condition [0x00007fc43f829000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c9d55b28> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:874)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:945)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"JBoss Shutdown Hook" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000041b59800 nid=0xba9 runnable [0x00007fc4530ca000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
    - locked <0x00000000f1e29d48> (a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:196)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:41)
    at java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.<init>(NoSuchMethodException.java:32)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.SecurityActions$2.run(SecurityActions.java:58)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.SecurityActions$2.run(SecurityActions.java:55)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.SecurityActions.getDeclaredMethod(SecurityActions.java:53)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.ClassHelper.getDeclaredMethod(ClassHelper.java:165)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.ClassHelper.getDeclaredMethod(ClassHelper.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.ClassHelper.getDeclaredMethod(ClassHelper.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.ClassHelper.getMethod(ClassHelper.java:138)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.lang.ClassHelper.isOverridden(ClassHelper.java:229)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.LifecycleCallbacks.createLifecycleCallbackInterceptors(LifecycleCallbacks.java:99)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokeCallback(EJBContainer.java:1112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokePreDestroy(EJBContainer.java:1149)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.remove(AbstractPool.java:112)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.InfinitePool.destroy(InfinitePool.java:44)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.pool.ThreadlocalPool.destroy(ThreadlocalPool.java:71)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.lockedStop(EJBContainer.java:934)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.lockedStop(SessionContainer.java:276)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.lockedStop(SessionSpecContainer.java:588)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.lockedStop(StatelessContainer.java:221)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.stop(EJBContainer.java:923)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5513.invoke(Unknown Source)
```